# Logging on to XMPP using libjingle

Tags: multithreading, xmpp, libjingle

I am writing some code using libjingle and having trouble with the first step: logging on to the XMPP server. My code is based on the [sample code from goog](https://developers.google.com/talk/libjingle/login) and the pcp sample code. That code confuses me a bit because it appears to only run one thread, so I realize this is an extremely basic question.

Anyway, here's the meat and potatoes of my code:

```
    talk_base::PhysicalSocketServer ss;
    talk_base::AutoThread main_thread(&ss);
    buzz::Jid jid( xmppUsername + "@" + xmppHost );
    if (!jid.IsValid() || jid.node() == "")
        throw "Invalid JID. JIDs should be in the form user@domain" ;

    buzz::TlsOptions tls = buzz::TLS_ENABLED;

    buzz::XmppClientSettings xcs;
    xcs.set_user(jid.node());
    xcs.set_host(jid.domain());
    xcs.set_resource("pcp");
    xcs.set_pass(talk_base::CryptString(pass));
    xcs.set_allow_plain(true);
    xcs.set_server(talk_base::SocketAddress(xmppHost.c_str(), 5222));
    xcs.set_use_tls(tls);

    // Log in.
    CustomXmppPump pump;
    pump.client()->SignalLogInput.connect(&debug_log_, &DebugLog::Input);
    pump.client()->SignalLogOutput.connect(&debug_log_, &DebugLog::Output);
    pump.DoLogin(xcs, new XmppSocket(tls), 0);

    // Wait until login succeeds.
    std::vector<uint32> ids;
    ids.push_back(MSG_LOGIN_COMPLETE);
    ids.push_back(MSG_LOGIN_FAILED);
    if (MSG_LOGIN_FAILED == Loop(ids))
        throw "Failed to connect";

    ...

    // Runs the current thread until a message with the given ID is seen.
    uint32 Loop(const std::vector<uint32>& ids) {
      talk_base::Message msg;
      while (talk_base::Thread::Current()->Get(&msg)) {
        cout << "received message: " << msg.message_id << endl;
        if (msg.phandler == NULL) {
          if (std::find(ids.begin(), ids.end(), msg.message_id) != ids.end())
            return msg.message_id;
          std::cout << "orphaned message: " << msg.message_id << endl;
          continue;
        }
        cout << "1: " << msg.message_id <<  " : " << msg.ts_sensitive << endl;
        talk_base::Thread::Current()->Dispatch(&msg);
        cout << "2: " << msg.message_id << endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

When run, it outputs:

```
connecting...
received message: 0
1: 0 : 0
[004:722] Resolving addr in PhysicalSocket::Connect
2: 0
received message: 0
1: 0 : 0
2: 0
```

And just hangs, so clearly it's getting stuck on the Get(&msg) call.

I should note that my server uses the DNS SRV record and works fine with other clients -- maybe I just need to resolve the SRV myself?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

T answer my own question:

According to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=386), and my own testing, dns SRV is not supported.

Moreover, according to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=294), the docs are very out of date, and the sample code I was using are not the recommended sample code.

Nevertheless, I was able to make some progress logging on by setting the domain in this call:

```
xcs.set_server(talk_base::SocketAddress(xmppHost.c_str(), 5222));
```

to the values of the actual server hosting the service. I thought I had tried this already, but it didn't work because I had actually changed this:

```
xcs.set_host(jid.domain());
```

Oops.

Comment: For anyone else going down this path, I would suggest looking at the call example for the most current way to login via XMPP with libjingle.